# Sitecore Indexing Manager Not Opening: Throws Exception

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

We upgraded from Sitecore 7.0 Initial (130424, April 24, 2013) to Sitecore 7.0 (130918, September 18, 2013)

The indexes I created in Initial no longer work in the new version.  The old version which is still up correctly indexes and shows up.

This is what shows up in Initial.

- Rebuild Time: 13 seconds
- Approximate Throughput: 64 items per second
- Has Deletions: False
  Is Clean: False
  Out of Date : False
  Document Count : 838
  Is Healthy : False
  Number of Fields : 55
  Last Updated : 12/3/2013
  Number of Terms : -1

This is the exception we get below when attempting to open the Indexing Manager.  The window that normally appears shows the below exception instead.

Attached is also a copy of the index config file in question.

Could not find add method: SetCommitPolicy (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex)

A ticket has also been created with Sitecore. Will include fix information if they have one.

[image: Sitecore Index][image: Exception from Sitecore 7.0 Indexing Manager]

Comment: It sounds like older Sitecore DLLs are getting deployed and there is a mish-mash of versions - double check your references and version numbers (in your project as well as your final inetpub directory). Also watch out for changes in the config file - Sitecore changed the casing from TitleCase to pascalCase and it might mean that some of your changes are now getting merged to the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing these lines of code to the 2nd set of code fixed the issue.  In Sitecore 7.0 Initial this code worked correctly but not in Sitecore 7.0 (130918).

```
<commitPolicy hint="raw:SetCommitPolicy">
   <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
</commitPolicy>
<commitPolicyExecutor hint="raw:SetCommitPolicyExecutor">
   <policyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
</commitPolicyExecutor>
```

This code makes the index work correctly in Sitecore 7.0 (130918)

```
<commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
        <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
    </policies>
</commitPolicyExecutor>
```

Comment: I only replaced <commitPolicyExecutor> but you have to replace both of them in the upgrade process.